# Why is this Takagi's function continuous?

Tags: continuity, uniform-convergence

1903 Takagi constructed the function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) := \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k} \mathrm{dist}(2^k x, \mathbb{Z})$ where $\mathrm{dist}(x,A) := \inf\{|x-y| : y \in A\}$ and proved it to be continuous but nowhere differentiable. Google finds some papers, but I am unable to find an easy proof for the function being continuous. (The fact that this function is nowhere differentiable seems to be more interesting to many papers …)

My own try: All partial sums are continuous as compositions of continuous functions, so I  “only” have to show that the partial sums converge uniformly to $f$. But how to do that?

Comment: Hint: What's the largest possible value of $\mathrm{dist}(2^k x, \mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: 1, obviously. So the series converges by the comparision test, sure. But just pointwise? Or is there a theorem like "monotonous and pointwise convergence implies uniform convergence"?

Comment: Not pointwise, uniformly. Look at it again carefully.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. My try: (I am unable to give an answer on my own question due to a lack of reputation …)

The fact I forget above is that uniform convergence is the same as convergence of the function in the $\infty$-norm. So let $f_n$ be $n$th partial sum, then:

$$||f - f_n||_\infty = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty 2^{-k} \mathrm{dist}(2^k x,\mathbb{Z}) \le \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty 2^{-k} \rightarrow 0$$
for $n \rightarrow \infty$. So $f_n$ converge uniformly to $f$, therefore $f$ is continuous.

Comment: You've done it!

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot then. :)